# What is the right way to start a sentence: "To avoid wasting time trying to figure out" or "To avoid to waste time trying to figuring out"?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, bare-infinitive

I have some problems when it comes to the usage of "to" vs "ing" to express the infinite form like in:

> [1] To avoid wasting time trying to figure out ..."
> [2] To avoid to waste time trying to figuring out ..."

what is the right way to start the sentence and why prefering "to" or "-ing"?

Comment: [2] is ungrammatical because the infinitival "to waste time ..." cannot satisfy the complement requirements of "avoid", which requires a gerund-participial clause as in [1].

Comment: "Trying to figuring out" is incorrect too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *To avoid wasting time trying to figure out* ...
>
> [2] **To avoid to waste time trying to figuring out* ...

[1] is fine, but [2] is ungrammatical because the infinitival clause "to waste time ..." cannot satisfy the complement requirements of the verb "avoid", which requires a gerund-participial clause as in [1].

Comment: so the [1] is correct? what about "To avoid wasting time trying figuring out"?

Comment: Yes, [1] is fine. Your new example is ungrammatical: the two _ing_ forms "trying and "figuring" do not work well together. We call this the 'doubl-_ing_ constraint'. You want "trying to figure out ...".

Answer (score 0):

The to-infinitive does not sound natural to me; moreover an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&content=To+avoid+wasting+time%2CTo+avoid+to+waste+time&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTo%20avoid%20wasting%20time%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CTo%20avoid%20wasting%20time%3B%2Cc0) shows that it is not used.

[image]